# Hosting a Javascript Source File on to Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gupshup

I am new to Firebase and thus I am asking this question. Also, I searched something similar to this question, tried them but failed. Thus when writing the reply, it would be great, if someone can add even the significance of the steps.

I have developed a chatbot and code at the following url being loaded when I use the web widget provided by the framework:

```
http://www.buildquickbots.com/botwidget/v2/demo/static/js/sdk.js
```

Every time user clicks on the webwidget, the above url gets opened which I doesn't want to happen. Thus I planned to host the code at the above url on to Firebase so that when user clicks on the widget something like myapp.fireabse.com/botwidget/v2/demo/static/js/sdk.js opens up.

How can I do this with nodejs backend?

Comment: You question is very confusing. Consider re-phrasing it.

Answer (score 0):

The [sdk.js](http://www.buildquickbots.com/botwidget/v2/demo/static/js/sdk.js) URL which creates an iframe and appends it your website in a widget. And this domain name is only visible only if you inspect the browser. Check Liva widget: http://www.livafluidfashion.com/

**Solution 1:**
If you want to see the domain name as *myapp.fireabse.com* then redirect the incoming traffic from "myapp.fireabse.com/botwidget/*" to "www.buildquickbots.com/botwidget/".

**Solution 2:**
You can get "firebase.buildquickbots.com" as a domain name also. For that, you have to talk/mail to Gupshup support people.